# PowerPoint vba - For each shape in each Layout in MasterView

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to programatically change the language of each shape in each customlayout in a PowerPoint template and I can't figure out how to do this. I've done it before, but I can't find the macro anymore so I don't really know how I did it. I've been able to select each custom layout though. But I need to loop through each textbox in each layout and select the language as well. My problem is targetting each shape. How do I do this?

This is what I've got so far:

```
ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlideMaster

For Each oLayout In ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
    oLayout.Select
Next
```

This basically loops through each layout. But I can't figure out how to select each placeholder? How do I do this?

Edit: Resolution is now:

```
For Each oLayout In ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
    oLayout.Select
    Dim oShape As Shape
    For Each oShape In oLayout.Shapes
        oShape.Select
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through `oLayout.Shapes`, or perhaps `oLayout.Shapes.Placeholders`.

Comment: Oh, that actually worked.. I just had to Dim oShape as Shape. Weird I didn't think of this yesterday! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you two.  I needed a solution to updating an embedded Excel object on the master slide.
This lead me to the perfect solution

```
'loops through all shapes in slidemaster
    Dim oShape As Shape
    For Each oShape In ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes
        oShape.Select
        'checks for excel object (type=7)
                 If oShape.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
                    oShape.OLEFormat.Activate

                    ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect  'deactivates shape
                End If
    Next
```